# How To Fix Resource Error from Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml, maui

I have a problem when using RC1 of MAUI that caused me to remove this part from the Android manifest:

```
    <application
      ...
      android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"
      ...>
    </application>
```

Now that it has GA'd, I'm trying to add it back in because in Android my application icon is not displayed - instead it's just the generic Android icon.  When I add this back into my Android manifest like so:

```
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round">
    </application>
```

I get compile errors that I have no idea how to resolve.  NOTE:  I DO have a file called "appicon.png", and it DOES work correctly as the application icon on iOS.  The errors look like this:

```
APT2260 resource xml/microsoft_maui_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths (aka com.watchlikes.watchlikesapp:xml/microsoft_maui_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths) not found.

APT2260 resource style/Maui.SplashTheme (aka com.watchlikes.watchlikesapp:style/Maui.SplashTheme) not found.

APT2067 failed processing manifest.
```

If I take the android:icon and android:roundIcon attributes out of the manifest file it compiles correctly again.  Any idea on what this problem is, and/or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion to improve readability and add some tags. I hope it improves the post!

Comment: I just re-read the compile errors, and it seems like you're missing some built-in features that allows custom resources in a specific directory to be used. Maybe give us the whole block of compile errors to give us a better insight?

Comment: When odd errors crop up after updating to new version, and messing with details such as this, sometimes its easiest to create a brand new project, and copy your source files over. It might "just work". Then if you really care, you can go back and identify what is different.

Comment: Point taken ToolmakerSteve.  I did that today and I can at least compile again.  Apparently though there are a number of issues getting the app icon right in Android apps right now (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4340 and https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5652 for starters) and so I guess it's time to move onto something else and wait for a fix.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android under "Platform-specific configuration":

If your icons name is "testicon.svg" just change the manifest file like this:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/testicon" 
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/testicon_round">
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and my fix was to right click my 'appicon.svg' file, go to properties, and set the build action to a "MauiIcon". This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that this can happen is when you are moving around files in Visual Studio. The IDE then decide that it does not want to track the file, and adds the following line to the .csproj in the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Images\appicon.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Otherwise, just follow the steps in this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#platform-specific-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I have Perfomed following steps to resolve issue

1. Open Project Folder
2. Deleted Bin and Obj Folder.
3. Clean and Build the solution